# This bundle is invalid - The file extension must be .zip

Tags: objective-c, swift, app-store-connect, cocoapods

I built a very small app in swift using objective-c cocoapods.
I can build it on my phone, but every time I try to upload it on testflight, I receive an email with a message saying that:

```
This bundle is invalid - The file extension must be .zip
```

Any idea what could possibly cause that?

Comment: I got rid of cocoapod until it's stable. But there is this conversation going on right now: https://github.com/CocoaPods/swift/issues/21#issuecomment-71340966

Comment: Yes I know, but in the end, I found it is better to suspend cocoapod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by having spaces in the build source path that the `Pods-frameworks.sh` script attempts to check for symlink status. For example, this path references a build scheme called "MyApp QA", which causes the `-L` check to fail with `binary operator expected`, and ultimately copies the symlink file instead of the actual framework files:

> /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ecinfzhnelbxxegrpzcpwnezmvot/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp QA/BuildProductsPath/QA-iphoneos/Pods/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework

**The easiest way to get around this is to make sure that nothing in your build path has spaces. This includes your app name, scheme, build config, etc.**

A [pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/3125) has been merged to fix this, which will resolve the issue when the next version of CocoaPods is released.

Comment: I don't have spaces anywhere in those paths, neither I use CocoaPods for anything. This issue persists. (Using Xcode 6.2, Base SDK 8.2, iOS Deployment Target 7.0)

Comment: It could be the fault of a file in your bundle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29399777/22147